# WPF XAML - Property update in nested controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I have a control that exposes a string property named `HeaderText` in this way:

```
public partial class HeaderControl : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty HeaderTextProperty;    

    [Category("Header Properties")]
    public string HeaderText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderTextProperty, value); }
    }

    static HeaderControl()
    {
        HeaderTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderText", typeof(string), typeof(HeaderControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    }

    public HeaderControl()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**HeaderControl's Xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Col.HMI.Controls.HeaderControl"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<Border Background="{Binding Path=HeaderBackground}" >
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=HeaderText}" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="36" Margin="5"/>
</Border>
```

and I want to use this `HeaderControl` in another UserControl, in this way:

**OtherControl's Xaml:**

```
<controls:HeaderControl Grid.Row="0" HeaderText="DEMO" />
```

And this works without problems. **But** if I bind the `HeaderText` property to a string property in the `OtherControl` ViewModel, in this way:

```
    <controls:HeaderControl Grid.Row="0" HeaderText="{Binding Path=SummaryTitle}" />
```

the bind doesn't work.

This is the `SummaryTitle` property in the OtherControl ViewModel:

```
public string SummaryTitle
{
    get 
    { 
        return _summaryTitle; 
    }
    set 
    { 
        _summaryTitle = value; OnPropertyChanged("SummaryTitle"); 
    }
}
```

PS: I have other controls binded to the OtherControl View Model and they work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting DataContext of HeaderControl to itself in the constructor by doing this:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

That means, when you apply some binding to any of the properties in `HeaderControl`, the Binding engine tries to find the bound property (in your case SummaryTitle) in this control, which it wont find and will fail.

So, to fix your problem, do not set the DataContext of HeaderControl to itself in the Constructor and the Binding engine will try find the properties in the correct DataContext.

Update your HeaderControl constructor to the following, and the bindings should start to work:

```
public HeaderControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

What you are trying to do here is, You want to have DependencyProperty named `HeaderText` in your UserControl, so that it's value can be set via DataBinding, and then update a value of `TextBlock` in your UserControl with the value of that DependencyProperty.

You can achieve this by two ways:

1) By updating TextBlock Binding to use ElementNme and Path syntax, XAML would look like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.HeaderControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             x:Name="_This">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=_This, Path=HeaderText}" FontSize="24" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

With this approach, whenever the property HeaderText is changed either via Binding or explicitly setting the value.

2) By listening to property value changed event for `HeaderText` property and then updating the `TextBlock` accordingly.

For this approach your HeaderControl.xaml would look like:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.HeaderControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"             >
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockInUserControl"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and the HeaderControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class HeaderControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTextProperty;

    [Category("Header Properties")]
    public string HeaderText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderTextProperty, value); }
    }

    static HeaderControl()
    {
        HeaderTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderText", typeof (string), typeof (HeaderControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnHeaderTextPropertyChanged));
    }

    private static void OnHeaderTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var headerControl = (HeaderControl) dependencyObject;
        headerControl.UpdateTextBlock((string) dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue);
    }

    void UpdateTextBlock(string text)
    {
        TextBlockInUserControl.Text = text;
    }

    public HeaderControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, the `SummaryTitle` property is not inside the `HeaderControl`. Therefore, your answer does not seem to be correct.

Comment: @fmunkert I think, that's what I mentioned: SummaryTitle is not part of HeaderControl, but the BindingEngine will try to find it in HeaderControl, since he set the DataContext to itself. So, in my answer I asked the OP to not to set the DataContext of HeaderControl to itself in it constructor, so that Binding engine will look for SummaryTitle in the correct DataContext.

Comment: I misunderstood your answer; I was under the impression you wanted to express the exact opposite. Sorry for that.

Comment: @fmunkert No problem. I updated my answer a bit for more clarity.

Comment: This doesn't work. Removing this.DataContext = this The bind doesn't work and if I set the title manually (like HeaderText="foo") it doesn't work too.

Comment: Could you update your question with details on how you setting OtherControlViewModel as datacontext? Also, Xaml for HeaderControl.

Comment: @sthotakura Question updated. The DataContext in OtherControl works fine because binding with other properties in OtherControlViewModel works fine; anyway this is how I set DataContext in OtherControl control: _dataCtx = new SummaryControlViewModel(); this.DataContext = _dataCtx;